# How do I run a function from a make-shift console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create a console. Let's say I a function `foo()` and I enter it into the "console". The console should run that function. I attempted the following:

```js
var $console = $('.console');
var console = {
 log: function(txt) {
  $console.append(txt + '<br>');
 },
 clear: function() {
  $console.text(' ');
 }
}
function foo() {
  console.log('foo ran');
}
var bKeys = [];
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
 if (event.which === 13) {
  //run the provided function from the input
    ($('.run').text())();
 }
});
```

```css
.console {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
.run {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 295px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='console'><input class='run' type='text' placeholder='Run a command...'/>Console: <br> </div>
```

What I tried was returning the text and trying to run that function after <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed in the `<input>`. However, that isn't working. How can I run a typed function from `<input>`?

Comment: OK, what is the question

Comment: @nbokmans I'm trying to run a function from the console that I'm making through `<input>`, but I have no idea how do that. So, how do I do that?

Comment: You _could_ (read: **[don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)**) use `eval()` - But, why would you do this?

Comment: @Lewis I'm using codepen and there's no console. Also, I'm coding at school and I can't open the Google Chrome's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a new debugger panel like every browser have built-in, you need a lot of things. If you want to allow running really any JS code, you might use `eval(userInputText)`. This may be dangerous if you don't validate `userInputText` and don't handle errors.

But if you just want to allow calling predefined commands from a fixed list, and here is an idea to start:

- Add an event handler to the input to detect when its content changes.
- Read out the content, this will be the key, the command's name.
- Create an object/array/dictionary of allowed/possible commands. The key/index should be the command's name, the value is a function.
- When the input changes, validate it, then run something like `commandStorage[userInputText]()`.
- You can extend this to pass parameters, add complex calls, anything.